# How to increase maximum upload file size in WordPress using .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

How to increase maximum upload file size in WordPress using .htaccess?

Been trying to increase the max upload file size in WordPress. Tried changing php in cPanel but couldn't get that to work.
Tried typing this code into the .htaccess editor plugin:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

but it keeps telling me syntax error. I'm placing it after the #END WordPress line too.

Comment: Please include the full error, and make sure that it is related to these values by removing the lines and reloading the file to ensure that the error is no longer there.

Comment: Whenever I type those lines into the .htaccess editor, it just states syntax error. Without those lines, the file works and there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [ini_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) in wp_config.php

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '128M');
ini_set(' post_max_size', '128M');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.htaccess
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300

Functions.php
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );

php.ini put on root directory where your .htaccess located
upload_max_filesize = 25M
post_max_size = 13M
memory_limit = 15M

wp-config.php
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '20M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '13M');
@ini_set( 'memory_limit', '15M' );
```